# Creating Matrix with a loop in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave, linear-algebra

I want to create a matrix of the following form

```
    Y = [1 x x.^2 x.^3 x.^4 x.^5 ... x.^100]
```

Let x be a column vector.
or even some more variants such as

```
    Y = [1 x1 x2 x3 (x1).^2 (x2).^2 (x3).^2 (x1.x2) (x2.x3) (x3.x1)]
```

Let x1,x2 and x3 be column vectors
Let us consider the first one. I tried using something like

```
    Y = [1 : x : x.^100]
```

But this also didn't work because it means take Y = [1 x 2.*x 3.*x ... x.^100] ?
(ie all values between 1 to x.^100 with difference x)
So, this also cannot be used to generate such a matrix.
Please consider x = [1; 2; 3; 4];
and suggest a way to generate this matrix

```
    Y = [1 1 1 1 1;
         1 2 4 8 16;
         1 3 9 27 81;
         1 4 16 64 256];
```

without manually having to write

```
    Y = [ones(size(x,1)) x x.^2 x.^3 x.^4]
```

Comment: You are looking for a variation of the Vandermonde matrix. See ``doc vander`` for an idea how to get this done.

Comment: It seems like you already have an answer with bsxfun. To understand why your attempt did not work I will show you how to get the powers of a scalar. This could be done like so: `5.^[1 2 3]` (Opposed to your `[1:5:5^3]` which just walks from 1 to 125 in steps of 5). The `bsxfun` solution below is basically an extention of my example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this `bsxfun` technique -

```
N = 5; %// Number of columns needed in output
x = [1; 2; 3; 4]; %// or [1:4]'
Y = bsxfun(@power,x,[0:N-1])
```

Output -

```
Y =
     1     1     1     1     1
     1     2     4     8    16
     1     3     9    27    81
     1     4    16    64   256
```

---

If you have `x = [1 2; 3 4; 5 6]` and you want `Y = [1 1 1 2 4; 1 3 9 4 16; 1 5 25 6 36]` i.e. `Y = [ 1 x1 x1.^2 x2 x2.^2 ]` for column vectors `x1`, `x2` ..., you can use this one-liner -

```
[ones(size(x,1),1) reshape(bsxfun(@power,permute(x,[1 3 2]),1:2),size(x,1),[])]
```

Comment: Suppose I have x = [1 2; 3 4; 5 6] and I want Y = [1 1 1 2 4; 1 3 9 4 16; 1 5 25 6 36] ie Y = [ 1 x1 x1.^2 x2 x2.^2 ] for column vectors x1, x2.. How do I modify it?

Comment: @ronilp Try this - `[ones(size(x,1),1) reshape(bsxfun(@power,permute(x,[1 3 2]),1:2),size(x,1),[])]` . Check out the edits too.

Comment: It must return something like x.^(1:2), but what exactly does 1:2 mean?

Comment: @ronilp With `bsxfun(@power, col_vector, row_vector)`, MATLAB creates a 2D matrix whose columns are `col_vector.^row_vector(1)`, `col_vector.^row_vector(2)` and so on.
In your case the col_vector is `x` and `1:2` is the row_vector. Hope this makes sense!

Comment: I misinterpreted the documentation. Got it now, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Using an adapted Version of the code found in Matlabs vander()-Function (which is also to be found in the polyfit-function) one can get a significant speedup compared to Divakars nice and short solution if you use something like this:

```
N = 5;
x = [1:4]';
V(:,n+1) = ones(length(x),1);
for j = n:-1:1
   V(:,j) = x.*V(:,j+1);
end
V = V(:,end:-1:1);
```

It is about twice as fast for the example given and it gets about 20 times as fast if i set `N=50` and `x = [1:40]'`. Although I state that is not easy to compare the times, just as an option if speed is an issue, you might have a look at this solution.

Comment: This version is faster, but repeated multiplying can result in precision errors.

Comment: @Daniel good point.From my understanding, it shouldn't make a difference for integers, though. But i don't really know that. I would be happy about clarification on that.

Comment: You code uses double values, there is a precision error multiplying integers when the numbers get larger than '2^53-1'

Answer (score 1):

in octave, broadcasting allows to write

```
N=5;
x = [1; 2; 3; 4];
y = x.^(0:N-1)
```

output -

```
y =

     1     1     1     1     1
     1     2     4     8    16
     1     3     9    27    81
     1     4    16    64   256
```